# Is it possible to ZAP scan on Heroku app?

Tags: appexchange

My Salesforce app is integrated with Heroku.
As per Salesforce rule, We need to perform Security scan using ZAP, if Salesforce app is integrated with external app.

Is it necessary to do ZAP scanning for Heroku?
If yes, then how can i do ZAP scan with Heroku, as Heroku dose not have UI events to execute use-case manually.